# Algebraic simplifications in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I have been playing around with basic examples of proofs in Isabelle.

Consider the following simple proof:

```
lemma
    fixes n::nat
    shows "n*(n+1) = n^2 + n"
    by simp
```

It seems to me that a powerful proof assistant like Isabelle should be able to prove this lemma without much guidance.
However, I was surprised to find out that Isabelle actually fails at applying the rule *simp* here (I also tried other "generic" rules like *simp_all*, *auto*, *force*, *blast* but the result is the same).

If I replace the last line by the following, then it works out:

```
by (simp add: power2_eq_square)
```

My concern is that I feel like I shouldn't have had to tell the system about the specific rule *power2_eq_square* to complete this proof.

Playing around with similar trivial examples, I found that *simp* is able to prove

```
n*(n+2)=n*n+n*2
```

but fails with

```
n*(n+3)=n*n+n*3
```

The last example is proven

```
by (simp add: distrib_left)
```

It is a complete mystery to me why I need to specify *distrib_left* in that second example, but not in the first (why is that?).

I have given these examples not for their own sake, but mainly to illustrate my main question:

> Is there a way to automate the verification of routine algebraic identities such as the above in Isabelle? If there isn't, then why not? What are the technical obstacles?

Answer (score 3):

Daily proof work indeed often stumbles over »routine algebraic identities«; but after some practical experience one usually develops some intuition how to solve such problems effectively.  A pattern I have developed over the years, by example:

```
context semidom
begin

lemma "a * (b ^ 2 + c) + 2 = a * b * b + c * a + 2"
```

A typical explorative proof starts with

```
  apply auto
```

Then associativity and commutative are considered also

```
  apply (auto simp add: ac_simps)
```

Then more algebaic normalizing rules are applied

```
  apply (auto simp add: algebra_simps)
```

The last gap is then easily filled by sledgehammer

```
  apply (simp add: power2_eq_square)
```

After that, the proof can be compactified

```
  by (simp add: algebra_simps power2_eq_square)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot (if I had the reputation I would upvote). Your strategy works well for me, but it still feels like a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The lemma

```
lemma power2_eq_square: "a^2 = a * a"
```

is not a good rewrite rule in general, as it will easily blow up the size of terms. So it is expected that a term rewriting based automation like `simp` will not apply this without you telling it to.

What you want is some sort of *proof search*, and Isabelle provides that: After writing your lemma, you can invoke the `sledgehammer` tool, and it will readily and quickly find the proof for you:

```
Sledgehammering... 
Proof found... 
"z3": Try this: by (simp add: power2_eq_square) (1 ms) 
"cvc4": Try this: by (simp add: power2_eq_square) (5 ms)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't really help me. I know about sledgehammer. That's how I knew to use power2_eq_square. Sledgehammer unfortunately fails desperately at only slightly more complicated algebraic simplifications.

Comment: Unfortunately, Isabelle is not a computer algebra system. It is a generic theorem prover, and while it provides some specialised automation for things algebraic problems, it is still far from the capabilities of a CAS like Mathematica. It is, of course, possible to improve this situation, but it's not as easy as one might think.

Comment: @ManuelEberl: Yes, I was afraid that was the case. Still, I don't understand why. Why can't there be a specific proof method in the spirit of "by algebra" ? It should simply try to show that the difference of two sides of an identity simplifies to 0 by expanding out everything and collecting terms.

Comment: There is a proof method called ‘algebra’ that does something like that. I think it uses Gröbner bases. It doesn't work on the `semidom` class though; I think you need a ring for it. However, as soon as you add division into the mix, things become more complicated again. For example if you have something like `a / (b * c * d * e) = …` where the sub-terms are something complicated and you simply multiply out everything, it will suddenly become much more difficult to recognise that the denominator is non-zero.

Comment: Things become even more tricky when you have additional assumptions like `cos x ^ 2 + sin x ^ 2 = 1`. I'm not an expert on this and I'm sure these procedures could be improved, but at the end of the day, someone who knows both Isabelle very well and is also familiar with the theory of solving such equations has to put the work in, and apparently no such person exists at the moment or is interested in doing this.